# How do i circumvent the bug at the end of lvl 1

Tags: tomb-raider-guardian

There is a known bug at the end of Tombraider "Guardian of Light" where once you finish playing level one, the game crashes. Is there any way to get to level two, so i can finish the game?

My platform:
Win 7 
Nvidia Grafics Card

Comment: Can you clarify if this is with respect to TR:Guardian of Light or TR:Legend?  I don't see that there is a "Legend of the Guardians" version.  Also, can you clarify what platform you are playing the game on?

Comment: sorry, got some things confused. edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is keep trying does not help. The savepoint is at the end of a difficult task. 
What i did was load a savegame from next level and went from there.

http://tombraiders.net/stella/walks/LCGOLwalk/savefiles.html

cheers

Answer (score 0):

[This unofficial forum](http://www.tombraiderforums.com/showthread.php?t=172208) lists the fix as "keep trying".  Apparently it can be gotten around with multiple attempts/perseverance.  I am assuming this is the  "known bug" you are referring to.

> Level name: Temple of Light
>
> Platform: PC
>
> Description: Game freezes and crashes after boulder hits the floor at the top of the ´staircase´ trap
>
> Fix: Keep trying